# What is the diffrence between ShapeBorderClipper class and CustomClipper<T> class

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I wanted to know what is the diffrence  between ShapeBorderClipper class and CustomClipper class  and when is the best to use each one of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ShapeBorderClipper` is a special type of `CustomClipper`, which according to its [documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/ShapeBorderClipper-class.html) clips to the outer path of a `ShapeBorder`. And as you know `CustomClipper` is used to customize the clipping behavior of clip widgets such as `ClipRRect` and `ClipOval`.
As for when it is suitable to use each one you should opt for `CustomClipper` when you want to alter the behavior of a `Clip` widget. and use `ShapeBorderClipper` if you want to a new shape based on the mix of the current widget border and the `ShapeBorder` provided to `ShapeBorderClipper`.

Comment: that was a bit helpful